# Using tool from ArcToolbox gives error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

I have problem with ran tool from ArcToolbox. When I run any tool, I get error:

> Content within this application coming from the website listed is
>   being blocked by Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration.

[image]

I work on Windows Serwer 2012 R2 and use ArcGis for Desktop 10.3.1

I try:

- reinstall ArcGis for Desktop 10.3.1
- to activate ActiveX (http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011895)
- add `http://localhost` to trusted sites (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/configure-trusted-sites-internet-explorer-group-policy/)

But problem still exists.
How to fix this?

Comment: Haven't you tried to add localhost to Trusted sites zone as it's written in the error message?

Comment: Please always include full error messages as text, not just as pictures, so that they are available to future searches.

Comment: Does the error message stop the tool from running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1:  Remove IE enhanced security configuration

https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-disable-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-ie-esc-in-windows-server-2012/

Option 2:  Adjust Active X filtering in IE settings:

http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011895

Option 3:  Since adding localhost didn't work, do you need to add a server address? (do you have ArcGIS server installed?)

http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010629